# Powershell Text Color

Tags: powershell

I have a small Powershell script that I run to show HR the status of a terminated user account.  Is there a way to have the color change from the default to RED if the LastLogonDate exceeds the time of the ModifiedDate?

```
Get-ADUser $User1 -Properties Name, Enabled, UserPrincipalName, LastLogonDate, Modified | Select Name, Enabled, UserPrincipalName, LastLogonDate, Modified
```

I'm not married to the code, so if there's a better way to do this, I'm interested in knowing more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you are working with a table.

You can change the whole table red or just add a warning in red.

I would just put a warning in red.

```
$table=Get-ADUser $User1 -Properties Name, Enabled, UserPrincipalName, LastLogonDate, Modified | Select Name, Enabled, UserPrincipalName, LastLogonDate, Modified


$orginal=[console]::ForegroundColor 

if (  $table.LastLogonDate -gt   $table.Modified) {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Warning! - Put info here!"
}
```

If you wanted to change the whole console color and change it back it is an option

```
$table=Get-ADUser $User1 -Properties Name, Enabled, UserPrincipalName, LastLogonDate, Modified | Select Name, Enabled, UserPrincipalName, LastLogonDate, Modified


$orginal=[console]::ForegroundColor 

if (  $table.LastLogonDate -gt   $table.Modified) {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Warning! - Put info here!"
    [console]::ForegroundColor = "Red"
    $table
    [console]::ForegroundColor = $orginal
} else {
    $table
}
```

Comment: The first option isn't working for me, but the second option ran.  It's the end of a very long day.  I'll try to sort it out when I have some free brain cycles again.  But thank you for the advice.

Comment: Nevermind... Got both to work.  Realized what was missing.  *derp*  Thanx again.